# Oracle Database Connection Running on Virtual Machine

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect to Oracle database hosted in a Linux Virtual Machine, using SQL Developer. Any leads on how to go about it?

I tried connecting using the IP address as HostName. But doesn't work.

Comment: Before we can help you, you need to, 1 - show us the error you get when you try to connect. 2 - Confirm your database is up and running AND available on the network from where you are running SQL Developer. But mostly #1 - there are literally dozens of connections errors for us to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer, create a new connection using the following

Connection Name:
Username: The username you use to log into the database
Password:
Hostname: The IP address of the virtual machine
Port: 1521
SID: The Oracle SID of the database you want to connect to

Comment: Thanks. I'm however, Still experiencing an error. See below:-  Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID)

Comment: That error message is a rather critical piece of information, and should have been included in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

> Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not
> establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID)

This error is almost always caused by a firewall. Make sure the local firewall on the database VM has opened the port 1521 for external connections. It can also sometimes be caused by anti-virus software on the client, preventing outgoing connections that haven't been whitelisted, but this is less common.